# AVPlayerLayer does not fill the UIVIew fully. What am I missing?

Tags: swift3, avplayerlayer

The video I'm playing does not take the entire area of the `UIView` (named videoView), which has a gray color: [iPhone 7 Plus Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrp2V.png)

Most of the answers claim that I need to either set the frame to bounds (of `UIView`) or set `videoGravity` to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`. I've tried both, but for some reason it still does not fill the space entirely.

```
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
var paused: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"HOTDOG", withExtension: "mp4")

    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)

    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds

    videoView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

After long time I found the answer.

Code below should be moved into viewDidAppear() like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Resizing the frame
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
    videoView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    avPlayer.play()
    paused = false
}
```

The layout was designed for iPhone SE (small screen), so when it was tested on a bigger screen the app was taking originally set size from the Auto-layout and shaping it according to that. By moving the code into viewDidAppear() the app resizes the window according to new constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the frame line `avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds` into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    avPlayerLayer.frame = videoView.layer.bounds
}
```

The rest should stick into the `viewDidLoad` function, just like you did.